# How can I debug a custom annotation in Lombok?

Tags: lombok

I am trying to extend [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org) by creating my own annotation.

I managed to have `LombokizedEclipse.launch` created by ant, and I have written `before` and `after` files.

`ant test` fails on my annotation (which is expected) and now I would like to debug my `Handle*` classes.

I am on a Mac, eclipse Luna 4.4 and java 1.8 update 45.

How can I do that? Please let me know if you need further info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't simply starting `LombokizedEclipse.launch` in debugger work for you? It starts another eclipse instance, which gets debugged in the first one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I now understand that `Lombok` can be debugged in 2 different ways:

1. Debug through Lombok JUnit tests(Thanks [Roel Spilker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31110277/1049952))
2. Debug in a second Eclipse instance started by the first instance

After cloning the [lombok](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok) repository, those are the steps I followed to achieve both methods:

### Debug through Lombok JUnit tests(Thanks [Roel Spilker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31110277/1049952))

1. `$ ant eclipse`
2. Import the (existing) project in Eclipse
3. `$ ant setupJavaOracle8TestEnvironment`
4. `$ ant dist`
5. `$ java -jar dist/lombok.jar`
6. Make sure the JDK8 configured in Eclipse is called `JavaSE-1.8`. Go to Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs to change it
7. Refresh Eclipse project (just press `F5`)
8. Right click the newly created Launch Configuration `RunLombokTests OracleJDK8.launch` and Run/Debug
9. `RunAllTests` is executed: `Runs: 455/454 (1 skipped), Errors: 0, Failures: 89`
10. `$ ant test` runs `RunAllTests` successfully: `Tests run: 455, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1`
11. NOTE: setting a breakpoint in e.g. `HandleGetter.handle` works
    I don't know why in Eclipse (step 9.) 89 tests fail in `TestWithEcj`, although the remaining 54 (and 1 skipped) pass.

### Debug in a second Eclipse instance started by the first instance

1. `$ ant dist`
2. `$ ant eclipseForDebugging`
3. Type in your eclipse installation (hint: it's the parent folder of the directory `plugins`)
4. Start Eclipse and refresh the project
5. Right click the newly created Launch Configuration `LombokizedEclipse.launch` and Run/Debug
6. Create a new project in the second Eclipse instance
7. Add your custom `lombok.jar` to the classpath
8. Annotate with Lombok (or your custom) annotation
9. The first Eclipse instance should take over if debugging (and if there are breakpoints)

Answer (score 2):

You can run the unit tests in Eclipse and set breakpoints. Run `/test/transform/src/lombok/transform/TestWithDelombok.java` for just testing javac and `/test/transform/src/lombok/transform/RunTransformTests.java` for running all tests.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.